# How to remove clk.konflab.com ads from chrome search results?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, adblock, advertisements

I have enabled AdBlock Plus extension as well as unchecked "allow non-intrusive ads" option. But I still see these ads when I search anything in google on Chrome browser.

[image: screenshot]

First I thought these were ads by google but it seems all these ads have the same URL format as below

> http://clk.konflab.com/?uid=****

I tried to find more information about konflab website, if it is some kind of malware, but could not find any information on googling.

How do I remove these ads and possible malware?

I am using Windows 10 and Chrome Version 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit)

Comment: The answers here may be helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit